# Fraction decimal for accuracy, recall, precision and f-measure

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn

I am conducting a CNN experiment and evaluate the built classifier using accuracy, recall, precision and f-measure metrics.

The resulted values are only two decimal fraction digits (i.e. 0.95). How can I have at least 4 fraction digits (i.e. 0.9532)

Further, how can I round the resulted values to have the floor or ceiling of the rounded number?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D,Activation,MaxPooling2D,Dense,Flatten,Dropout
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
import keras
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import pickle
from keras.models import load_model
classifier = load_model('32_With_Dropout_rl_001_1_layer_2.h5')
classifier1 = load_model('32_With_Dropout_rl_001_2_layers_2.h5')
classifier2 = load_model('32_With_Dropout_rl_001_3_layers_2.h5')
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
batchsize=10
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('/home/osboxes/Downloads/Downloads/Journal_Paper/Benign_Malicious/Spectrogram/Test/',
                                           target_size = (200,200),
                                           batch_size = batchsize,
                       shuffle=False,
                                           class_mode ='categorical')
Y_pred = classifier.predict_generator(test_set, steps= 1023 // batchsize+1)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix 1 layer')
print(confusion_matrix(test_set.classes, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = test_set.classes
class_labels = list(test_set.class_indices.keys()) 
target_names = ['Bening', 'Malicious'] 
report = classification_report(test_set.classes, y_pred, target_names=class_labels)
print(report) 

Y_pred = classifier1.predict_generator(test_set, steps= 1023 // batchsize+1)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix 2 layers')
print(confusion_matrix(test_set.classes, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = test_set.classes
class_labels = list(test_set.class_indices.keys()) 
target_names = ['Bening', 'Malicious'] 
report = classification_report(test_set.classes, y_pred, target_names=class_labels)
print(report) 

Y_pred = classifier2.predict_generator(test_set, steps= 1023 // batchsize+1)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)
print('Confusion Matrix 3 layers')
print(confusion_matrix(test_set.classes, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = test_set.classes
class_labels = list(test_set.class_indices.keys()) 
target_names = ['Bening', 'Malicious'] 
report = classification_report(test_set.classes, y_pred, target_names=class_labels)
print(report) 


#f = open('32_With_Dropout_rl_001_1_layer', 'rb')
#history = pickle.load(f)

#f = open('32_With_Dropout_rl_001_2_layers', 'rb')
#history1 = pickle.load(f)


#f = open('32_With_Dropout_rl_001_3_layers', 'rb')
#history2 = pickle.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to use the `output_dict` parameter when computing the classification report. If set to `True`, the output is returned as a dict (and not as a string). You can then access all the fields and modify them as you want (for example using `math.floor` or `math.ceil`).

```
from math import ceil, floor

# do your stuff here
report = classification_report(..., output_dict=True)
# use the values of the report dictionary as you wish
print(floor(report[...]))
```

If you want to get the report as a string then you should use the `digits` parameter:

```
report = classification_report(..., digits=4)
```

Check the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html).

Comment: Thanks! what about the number of digits for fractions?

Comment: @MaysaSarsour Your dict should already contain numbers with more than two fractional digits. Try to check it